# model.fit() gives me 'KeyError: input_1' in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Im trying to train resnet50 on the cifar10 dataset using keras. I have replaced the last fully connected layers with a dense layer with 10 neurons and softmax activation. Calling model.fit() gives me:

```
KeyError: 'input_1'
```

Below is the code to reproduce the result:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow import keras

train_ds = tfds.load('cifar10', split='train')
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(1000).batch(100)
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, input_shape=(32, 32, 3), pooling="avg")
x = model.output
x = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
model = keras.Model(model.input, x)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()], optimizer='Adam')
model.fit(x=train_ds, epochs=10)
```

And the call stack:

```
KeyError
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-71ed1fc54857> in <module>
     10 model = keras.Model(model.input, x)
     11 model.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()], optimizer='Adam')
---> 12 model.fit(x=train_ds, epochs=10)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    846                 batch_size=batch_size):
    847               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
--> 848               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
    849               # Catch OutOfRangeError for Datasets of unknown size.
    850               # This blocks until the batch has finished executing.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    578         xla_context.Exit()
    579     else:
--> 580       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    581 
    582     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    625       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    626       initializers = []
--> 627       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    628     finally:
    629       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    504     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    505         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 506             *args, **kwds))
    507 
    508     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2444       args, kwargs = None, None
   2445     with self._lock:
-> 2446       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2447     return graph_function
   2448 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2775 
   2776       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2777       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2778       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2779       return graph_function, args, kwargs

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2665             arg_names=arg_names,
   2666             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2667             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2668         self._function_attributes,
   2669         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    979         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    980 
--> 981       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    982 
    983       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    439         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    440         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 441         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    442     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    443 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

KeyError: in user code:

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:531 train_step  **
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:927 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py:719 call
        convert_kwargs_to_constants=base_layer_utils.call_context().saving)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py:826 _run_internal_graph
        inputs = self._flatten_to_reference_inputs(inputs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py:926 _flatten_to_reference_inputs
        return [tensors[inp._keras_history.layer.name] for inp in ref_inputs]
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py:926 <listcomp>
        return [tensors[inp._keras_history.layer.name] for inp in ref_inputs]

    KeyError: 'input_1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm note quite sure what goes wrong with your code, but this should do it for you:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow import keras

train_ds = tfds.load('cifar10', split='train')
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(1000).batch(100)

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
x = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling="avg")(inputs)
out = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
    metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()], 
    optimizer='Adam')
model.fit(x=train_ds, epochs=10)
```

So you define your own `Input` and use the `ResNet50` model as if it was a layer.

Comment: Thanks! But i get the exact same error on your code too. It happens after training for one full epoch.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Did you run the exact code snippet I provided? For me it works fine, multiple epochs (although I used dummy data). Which TensorFlow version you use? 
EDIT: Perhaps this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61994299/using-functional-api-in-tensorflow-throws-keyerror-input-1

Comment: Really weird, first it downloads the dataset, then it trains for one epoch and then the error happens. I tested it on a kaggle notebook and on my pc, got the same error on both.

Comment: Im gonna check the link out, looks promising :)

Comment: I think it might be something with the dataset... but not sure (takes too long for me to download so I can't check) :-(

Comment: Yep it was the dataset, it was an official one though. Im not gonna read the tutorial on how to convert the official dataset so it is actually usable. Instead im gonna go back to the PyTorch world where everything is logical and in order :))

Comment: Okay good luck! :-) Btw, this might be interesting to you (more similar to PyTorch): https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence. Which can be used with mode.fit().